# Files storage with doctrine and symfony 3?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony

I need help for create my entities whit doctrine 2 in my symfony3 app :

I would like my users can posts articles which content is:

- title
- author
- either one unique image (upload file)
- or one unique movie ($url)

What do you recommend ?
Should I build my article entity like this ?

```
class Article
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="author", type="integer")
     */
    private $author;

    /**
     * @var ?
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="image", type="?")
     */
    private $image;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="url_movie", type="string")
     */
    private $url_movie;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="media", type="integer")
     */
    private $media;
}
```

(in controller : if $media = 1 => this is an image, else this is a video)

Or use something like Relation One-To-One with a new entity "media" for example ?

What is the best way for my case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's normal. Sadly, the discriminator column is meant to be used by Doctrine, database side, therefore it's not accessible in your entity. There's two possible way to achieve what you want:

---

The first, using the children class name:

```
/**
 * Article
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="article")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="PM\PlatformBundle\Repository\ArticleRepository")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="media", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"article" = "Article", "movie" = "Movie", "image" = "Image"})
 */
class Article
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $title;

    //...

    /**
     * Get article type.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getType()
    {
        // This will return "movie" or "image"
        return strtolower(substr(strrchr(get_class($this), "\\"), 1));
    }
}

/**
 * Movie
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Movie extends Article
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="url", type="text")
     */
    private $url;

    //getter setter
}

/**
 * Image
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Image extends Article
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="path", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $path;

    //getter setter
}
```

---

The second, by declaring manually the type in your class:

```
/**
 * Article
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="article")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="PM\PlatformBundle\Repository\ArticleRepository")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="media", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"article" = "Article", "movie" = "Movie", "image" = "Image"})
 */
class Article
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $type;

    //...

    /**
     * Get article type.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getType()
    {
        return $this->type;
    }
}

/**
 * Movie
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Movie extends Article
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="url", type="text")
     */
    private $url;

    public function __construct() 
    {
        $this->type = 'movie';
    }

    //getter setter
}

/**
 * Image
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Image extends Article
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="path", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $path;

    public function __construct() 
    {
        $this->type = 'image';
    }

    //getter setter
}
```

---

Personnaly, I have a preference for the first solution. I find it cleaner, and more evolutive (this code will adapt if you have to add a third article type).

Of course, you can also use `instanceof` to determine which subclass is the Article entity you're manipulating.

Comment: Thank for help, but I have builded my own twig extension for test article type directly in my template and now it works perfectly ! No need to declaring manually the type or other method.

Comment: That's effectively another way to do it! I'm glad you achieved what you wanted. :)

Comment: I'am back here, currently I'am working on a way for add new article via a form. And I pretty confused. Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39791247/build-form-with-single-table-inheritance

Answer (score 1):

I think using a Media entity and handling the media type in the Media entity is the best way.

```
class Article
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    // ...

    /**
     * @var Media
     *
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Media")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="media_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $media;
}

class Media
{
    const TYPE_IMAGE = 'image';
    const TYPE_MOVIE = 'movie';

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $url;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $type;
}
```

An other way to do it could be to use [entity inheritance](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html) to have differents entities for images and movies - if you need to.

Comment: However I don't understand your media class above. Your classe has no attribute for the image path or movie's url. How it is working ?

Comment: I didn't push the reflexion that far :D I assumed (wrongly, I guess ^^) that your images were defined by URL too. If the way to manage them is different, that's the case where the entity inheritance could be a good option. The Media entity would then just be a class used to have only one attribute "media" in your Article entity, which can contain two different types of class.

Comment: Effectively is that. So in Doctrine's doc I have to choose between Single Table Inheritance and Class Table Inheritance ?

Comment: Yes! In most case, the single table inheritance is recommanded: it's the easiest way to do it, and for most situations, the most performant.

Comment: Ok I did it. I detail on my new answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I did a Single Table Inheritance on my article class :

```
/**
 * Article
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="article")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="PM\PlatformBundle\Repository\ArticleRepository")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="media", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"article" = "Article", "movie" = "Movie", "image" = "Image"})
 */
class Article
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $title;

    //...
}

/**
 * Movie
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Movie extends Article
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="url", type="text")
     */
    private $url;

    //getter setter
}

/**
 * Image
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Image extends Article
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="path", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $path;

    //getter setter
}
```

That works great !