# Build Form with Single Table Inheritance

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, symfony

I have my entity Article and one single table inheritance like this :

```
/**
 * Article
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="article")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="PM\PlatformBundle\Repository\ArticleRepository")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="media", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"article" = "Article", "movie" = "Movie", "image" = "Image", "text" = "Text"})
 */
class Article
{
    protected $id;
    protected $title;
    protected $description;
    protected $author;
    //other attributes and setters getters
}

class Image extends Article
{
    private $path;
    //getter setter
}

 class Movie extends Article
{
    private $url;
    //getter setter
}
```

So my article's object type is either Image or movie or text only. Ok now I would like build a form wherein users can post a new article : in this form, the user has to choice between tree type (3 radios button) : image OR movie OR text only and of course the other fields : title and description. How I can do that ? Because with the command

> php bin/console doctrine:generate:form myBundle:Article

The form rendered is :

```
class ArticleType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title',          TextType::class)
            ->add('description',    TextareaType::class)
            ->add('save',           SubmitType::class);
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'PM\PlatformBundle\Entity\Article'
        ));
    }
}
```

I don't know the way to implement my STI relation in this form. Because I have not field in my Article entity/object for the type (only in my table).
I have to add a Custom ChoiceType() field but it require a attribute.
When I try to add this in the form :

> ```
>         ->add('path',           SearchType::class)
>         ->add('url',            UrlType::class)
> ```

I got this error :

Neither the property "path" nor one of the methods "getPath()", "path()", "isPath()", "hasPath()", "__get()" exist and have public access in class "PM\PlatformBundle\Entity\Article".

Because I have create an instance of Article, not an instance of Image or Movie. Initially I created a STI thinking a new instance of Article would allow me also to define the "type" of article. But not ? Right ?

Comment: Add `mapped:false` option for form fields that shouldn't be mapped to attribute of underlying object (Article). Then you will have to find a way to handle this form properly on your own.

Comment: Hm I don't know if it's a good idea to use mapped:false. What should I do to recover path and url properly, because they really exists in my database and in my object (but via inheritance) ?

Comment: But you don't have `Image`/`Movie` object there, do you? No, you don't. So how should it work in your opinion (never mind if it's possible or not)?

Comment: Yes I have, look my first post above ! I have one class Movie and one Image (extends article).

Comment: You have a **class**, not an **object instance** passed to the form.

Comment: Yes but an object instance "article" which contains 2 others classes ? Not ?

Comment: Not. Why would it. You better get some basics of OOP first before diving info more advanced topics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to make three forms (one for an `Article`, one for a `Movie` and one for an `Image`). Then, in your controller, you have to options to deal with them:

- Either you use one action to handle the three forms (you can check wich one is submitted by using `$form->isSubmitted()`)
- You create one action by form, and [set the form action URL](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/action_method.html) for each form to the correct controller.

Finally, in your template, you encapsulate your forms in a div, and use the example in my previous post.

```
{% extends "CoreBundle::layout.html.twig" %}

{% block title %}{{ parent() }}{% endblock %}

{% block btn_scrollspy %}
{% endblock %}


{% block bundle_body %}
    <div class="well">
        <div class="selector">
            <input type="radio" name="form-selector" value="article-form"> Article
            <input type="radio" name="form-selector" value="movie-form"> Movie
            <input type="radio" name="form-selector" value="image-form"> Image
        </div>

        <div class="form article-form" style="display: none;">
            {{ form(articleForm) }}
        </div>
        <div class="form movie-form" style="display: none;">
            {{ form(movieForm) }}
        </div>
        <div class="form image-form" style="display: none;">
            {{ form(imageForm) }}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Can you explain me more precisly how do "one action by form, and set the form action URL for each form to the correct controller." ? Because I built 3 forms like you say and used bootstrap Toggelable option for view (replace your JS code for hide/show the correct form). It works great, but I can not make the system: one action by form because initially I have one route for one controller for one view and now I have 3 actions for 3 route for ONE view.

Comment: It's explained in the link in my answer how to define the action (=> URL which will be called when you submit your form) for your form. So in your forms, you just have to set the route that matches the right controller.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with dragoste in the comments: you can't expect the form to deduce by himself the type of class you want to instantiate based on a value.

Roughly, `Image` and `Movie` are the same type as `Article`, but an `Article` is not an `Image` and/or a `Movie`.

You will have to check that manually. You can do that server side like explained in the comments, with a field using `mapped: false` to determine the type of entity you need to instantiate, or client side with javascript by using three forms (one for a movie, one for an article, one for an image) and by displaying the correct one based on your radio button.

---

Edit: How to display the correct form in JS?

I created a JSFiddle to show you how you can do this using jQuery : https://jsfiddle.net/61gc6v16/

With jQuery documentation, you should be able to quickly understand what this sample do, and to adapt it to your needs. :)

Comment: Okay thank for your explaination! I would like to build this form system using javascript. But I have not the knowledge on JS or Jquery for this. It requires a lot of JS code?

Comment: I edited my answer. :) JavaScript is a good way to enhance your users experience and, in the same time, it can prevent you some headaches on how to handle things server side. You should take a look at it, as it is almost indispensable for web developers now, back or front. jQuery is a good start to catch the logic behind the language as it is pretty easy to learn and has great functionnalities. Nevertheless, keep in mind that knowing jQuery is not knowing JavaScript, and that there's a lot more frameworks that can provide you a lot more wonderful things. :)

Answer (score 0):

@Boulzy I did this and it works:

```
    class ArticleController extends Controller
    {
        public function addAction(Request $request)
        {
            $form1 = $this->get('form.factory')->create(TextOnlyType::class);
            $form2 = $this->get('form.factory')->create(ImageType::class);
            $form3 = $this->get('form.factory')->create(MovieType::class);
            return $this->render('PMPlatformBundle:Article:add.html.twig', array(
                'ArticleTextform' => $form1->createView(),
                'ArticleImageform' => $form2->createView(),
                'ArticleMovieform' => $form3->createView(),
            ));
        }

        public function addArticleTextAction(Request $request)
        {
            $ArticleText = new TextOnly;
            $form = $this->get('form.factory')->create(TextOnlyType::class, $ArticleText);
            if ($request->isMethod('POST') && $form->handleRequest($request)->isValid()) {
                $ArticleText->setAuthor(5);
                $ArticleText->setLikes(0);
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $em->persist($ArticleText);
                $em->flush();

                $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('notice', 'Annonce bien enregistrée.');

                $listComments = $ArticleText->getComments();
                return $this->render('PMPlatformBundle:Article:view.html.twig', array(
                    'article' => $ArticleText,
                    'listComments' => $listComments
                ));
            }
            return $this->render('PMPlatformBundle:Article:add.html.twig', array(
                'form' => $form->createView(),
            ));
        }

        public function addArticleImageAction(Request $request)
        {
           //the same system as TextOnly
        }

        public function addArticleMovieAction(Request $request)
        {
           //the same system as TextOnly
        }
}
```

(I override action directly in my template. With POST method.)
addAction is my contoller which is called by route for display the view of three forms. As you can see this code works as long as there is no error on submitted form. Because, in this case (when error occured when a form is submitted) each controller needs to return the initial view with the 3 forms. How I can do that ?

Comment: Take a look at these documentations, pick the one that seems the most interesting to you: http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/forwarding.html, https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html#redirecting. I'm glad that I can help, but you know I'm not going to code your entire website, right? I mean, trying, failing, trying again, doing mistakes and persisting are an immortant part of the learning process. You should try more solutions, do more research before comming here asking for help. You will learn better and faster this way.